# How to fill out "username" and "password" fields with PHP?

Tags: php, scrape

I want to scrape stats from an affiliate site with php.
I am pretty new to php but I know how to scrape data from a website, however affiliate sites need you to log in first.

How can I fill in the username and password fields and press the login button with php? Is it even possible to do this with php or do I need another programming language for it?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: do not think of it as "filling input fields". What really matters is sending the data via POST or GET, and you probably know how to do that =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to analyze the whole login process by using the Developer Tools in Google Chrome or Firebug in Firefox to see what fields are posted (form data).

After that you'll need to develop a cURL script based on your research.

[image]

Comment: Great! This is what I needed to get started. Thanks silkfire. BTW is scraping allowed on any website or do I have to ask permission for this?

Comment: @10now Better to consult with lawyer.

Comment: Ask the site owner first or read their Terms of Use. Their content is most probably copyright protected.